# How to STOP ListView from expanding to content

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I'm trying to make my xaml squeeze list items (images) to fit the initial window size, but they cant be fixed size because i want to scale them up as i increase the size of the window. Something like a ViewBox would do.

I load images from 2 folders (software and hardware). Number and size of the images will wary in the runtime so i want to make items be the same size regardless of images size or number of items.
That's why i used uniform grid as a items panel template.

But, this is the result I'm getting...

[image]

The ListView loads images in their full size and expands itself to fit them in, cutting of some of the items in the process.

This is my xaml:

```
<Window x:Class="WPF_UI_Testing.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WPF_UI_Testing"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="460" Width="640">


    <Grid>
        <ListView x:Name="listview1">

            <ListView.GroupStyle>
                <GroupStyle>
                    <GroupStyle.HeaderTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <StackPanel>
                                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}"
                                           FontWeight="Bold" FontSize="18" />
                            </StackPanel>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </GroupStyle.HeaderTemplate>
                    <GroupStyle.Panel>
                        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                            <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical"></StackPanel>
                        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
                    </GroupStyle.Panel>
                </GroupStyle>
            </ListView.GroupStyle>

            <ListView.ItemsPanel>
                <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                    <UniformGrid ></UniformGrid>
                </ItemsPanelTemplate>
            </ListView.ItemsPanel>

            <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <StackPanel>
                        <Image Source="{Binding problemImage}"/>
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding ImageName}"/>
                    </StackPanel>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListView.ItemTemplate>

        </ListView>
    </Grid> 
</Window>
```

Is there a way to prevent ListView from expanding beyond window borders when populated with content?

EDIT:

I packed the entire solution with some dummy data and images if anyone wants to have a go at this...
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1IWqxSR3kpsVdCm5Qcgn6QZbZhbYz52n2/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Did you try giving width and height to the `Image` controller?

Comment: Yes, but I don't want to do that because i don't want it to be fixed size. I want to be able to scale it up if i resize the window.
And if possible, would also like to avoid fiddling with min and max width and height.

Comment: The image has specific aspect ratio but window size can be whatever. Therefore, you have to take a width or height from window. If width, set container width as window width. And then uniform scale the images.

Comment: I think i get what you are saying, but since my container is inside of a listView i dont know how to target it.

Comment: As @donggas90 said you could have the Image Stretch set to uniform, and also disable the horizontal scrolling of the listview.

Comment: The `ListView` itself by default will stretch to fit its parent (when child of a control that controls its children's size e.g a `Grid`). Also the content will stretch beyond the `ListView` dimensions (view port) when it contains more items than it can actually fit. Disabling the `ScrollViewer` would make those item unreachable. To give the items a fixed size, set a `Style` to `ListView.ItemContainerStyle` and set `Width` and `Height` as needed. UniformGrid or the panel in general has no direct influence on the parent's (`ListViewItem`) size. Its only concern is to layout its child elements.

Comment: @o_w Disabling scrolling will cutoff my items i don't want that.

Comment: @BionicCode I don't want to give fixed size to my items. I want them to uniformly fill the available space, but that available space shouldn't exceed the space provided by the window.

Comment: @Frakula But you use UniformGrid already. Disabel the scroll, replace the horizontal item's StackPanel with Grid and put the Image in a star column, and set it's Stretch to uniform.

Comment: Uniform Grid behaves exactly as i want it IF used outside of ListView.
I want to replicate the same behavior but on the entire container inside of the ListView.
I dont know if we understand each other very well so i uploaded entire solution with images to google Drive (link is in the question) for anyone who wants to test the behavior for themselves.

Comment: @Frakula I have explained the basic layout behavior of the `ListView`. It's an `ItemsControl` whose purpose is to host an unlimited number of items in a limit layout space. To do this, it wraps it's content/items into a `ScrollViewer`. This allows to virtually extend the layout area. If it wasn't for the `ScrollViewer` items outside the layout area are just clipped to to remain invisible. It must be clear to you that you assign certain space/size as layout area for a control to render its content/children. If all child elements should be visible, they must fit into the available layout size.

Comment: @Frakula Either the parent grows to allow more children to be visible, or the parent uses a `ScrollViewer` or you shrink child elements to fit or you limit the number of child elements. If you want your parent to have a fixed size and all it's elements being visible your only solutions is to shrink items to fit. There is no control that does this, so you are left to implement this yourself. What you can do is to extend the `StackPanel` and override `MeasureOverride` and `ArrangeOverride`. The task is quite simple, but the result rather questionable regarding user experience.

Comment: @BionicCode Good explanation, thanks. I do understand how ListView uses space, i just thought there must be a simple way to change default behavior to achieve what im trying to do...
Perhaps I'm using a wrong control for this?
I managed to achieve desired outcome with just <Image> elements but i figured it would be easier to process selecting, hovering, importing unknown number of items,  etc with pre-made control.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `UniformGrid` does basically what you want. The idea to use it as item panel is also correct. The only problem that arises, aside from using item groups, is the fact that the `ListView` wraps its panel into a `ScrollViewer`, which results in items or the `UniformGrid` to resize differently as the `ScrollViewer` gives the panel no size restrictions. `UniformGrid` needs to be hosted in a fixed size container in order to be able to calculate its children's max sizes.

You should either use the `ItemsControl`

```
<ItemsControl>
  <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
    <ItemsPanelTemplate>
      <UniformGrid />
    </ItemsPanelTemplate>
  </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>

  <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
    <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type viewModels:DetailItem}">
      <StackPanel>
        <Image Source="{Binding problemImage}"/>
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding ImageName}"/>
      </StackPanel>
    </DataTemplate>
  </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
</ItemsControl>
```

or override the `ControlTemplate` of `ListView` and remove the `ScrollViewer` (if you need its additional features of `ListView`):

```
<ListView>
  <ListView.Template>
    <ControlTemplate TargetType="ListView">
      <Border BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}"
              BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}"
              Background="{TemplateBinding Background}">
        <ItemsPresenter />
      </Border>
    </ControlTemplate>
  </ListView.Template>

  <ListView.ItemsPanel>
    <ItemsPanelTemplate>
      <UniformGrid />
    </ItemsPanelTemplate>
  </ListView.ItemsPanel>

  <ListView.ItemTemplate>
    <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type viewModels:DetailItem}">
      <StackPanel>
        <Image Source="{Binding problemImage}"/>
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding ImageName}"/>
      </StackPanel>
    </DataTemplate>
  </ListView.ItemTemplate>
</ListView>
```

The limitations of this approach is when using groups to display the items. `UniformGrid` should handle `GroupItem` (nested items) not as expected.

As said in my previous comment, if you want to group items, you need to extend a panel of your choice to manually arrange `GroupItem` and it's children (nested `ItemsPresenter`). As you think about how to calculate sizes you may realizes that it is more complicated to calculate group item sizes with dynamic grouped item sizes.

I recommend to let go the grouping and use one of the above solutions or use grouping and embrace the `ScrollViewer`.

Comment: I choose to ditch groups, at least for now.
I accepted the answer even though this didn't completely solved my problem.
At least i can move on with the project :)